# Playstore - App getting rejected due to 'android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG'

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, calllog

In our android app we included ***android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG*** permission which is needed for our functionality. After integrate these permission and once we uploaded the app in PlayStore the app got rejected due to READ_CALL_LOG permission and received below message.

[image]

Can anybody please let me know how could solve this issue? I couldn't remove the 'READ_CALL_LOG' permission which is require in my project.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app can not declare READ_CALL_LOG permission in Manifest unless it was a dialer app.

If you feel, your app's major functionality depends on READ_CALL_LOG permission, you must [fill the declaration form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102) explaining why you need this permission.

If your request is accepted, your app will be allowed to use the permission.

Comment: llindra : Still app got rejected after filled the declaration form. Any idea?

Comment: If your app is NOT related to banking, antivirus, backup, dialer, automation; the chances of accepting your request are very low. If it is okay, please update your question with more details why you need READ_CALL_LOG permission in your app.

Also, add the response you received from Google after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Google has restricted SMS and CALL permissions for default apps only. Apps are getting rejected due to permissions declaration in the manifest file. There are alternate ways to get required permissions access in android applications.

Follow below link for more information.

[No more SMS and Call permissions](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827)

Comment: Still there is no alternative solution for CALL_LOG in the above link. Still my problem not resolved. 'These are quite a few alternatives which I could address for now. But this won’t cover everything. For eg, CALL_LOG, I didn’t find any alternative solution so far. If anybody found out anything, please do share.'